# React list rendering doesn't work - expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs, function, variable-assignment

So I have an App component in which I send a request to API and I get back individual games as objects. Then I put them into state as 'games' array and rendering them inside App component - it works this way.

```
const searchResult = games.map(game => {
    return <GameItem game={game} key={game.id}></GameItem>;
  });

  return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='header'>
          <Logo />
          <Navbar />
          <Search
            click={onClickHandler}
            search={searchInput}
            searchInput={handleSearchInput}
          />
        </div>

        {loading ? <Loading /> : searchResult}

      </div>
  );
```

The problem comes in when I'm trying to extract this searchResult into a new component called Games.

```
import React from 'react';
import GameItem from './GameItem';

const Games = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.games.map(game => {
                <GameItem game={game} key={game.id}/>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Games;
```

then at App.js changing this line

```
{loading ? <Loading /> : <Games games={games}/>}
```

I've tried few ways of returning this expression at Games component but it's always throwing me that error.

```
Line 8:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Have you got any ideas how can I extract this into a new component and get it to work?

Comment: You forgot the return in your map. `return <GameItem game={game} key={game.id}/>`

Comment: Or just get rid of the { and } if it's an arrow function with only one expression

Comment: Thank you guys. I totally forgot about returning in the map method. Finally managed to get it working :)

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
props.games.map(game => {
                <GameItem game={game} key={game.id}/>
            }
```

`<GameItem game={game} key={game.id}/>` is an *expression* that you do nothing with (hence the error).

This is because you use `game => {/*...*/}` instead of `game => expression`. When you have the `{}`, you need to `return` something to provide any result for the `map` iteration. When you omit the `{}`, you automatically "return" the given expression.